# VB.NET Custom Game Launcher "If" statement error:

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Lately I have been trying to build a custom launcher for my Java game in VB.NET.
The only problem is that the code:

```
Dim appData As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\.ProjectSpideynn\"

Public Async Sub Start_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Start.Click
    If File.Exists(appData & "Pulsar\ProjectSpideynn-Pulsar.jar") Then
        Dim startInfo As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        startInfo.Arguments = "java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar" & appData & "Pulsar\ProjectSpideynn-Pulsar.jar"
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
        Process.Start(startInfo)
    End If
    If Not File.Exists(appData & "Pulsar\ProjectSpideynn-Pulsar.jar") Then
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("*hidden-link*", appData & "\.ProjectSpideynn\Pulsar\ProjectSpideynn-Pulsar.jar")
        Dim startInfo As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
        startInfo.FileName = "javaw.exe"
        startInfo.Arguments = "-Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar" & appData & "Pulsar\ProjectSpideynn-Pulsar.jar"
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
        Process.Start(startInfo)
    End If
End Sub
```

It errors at the `If Not File.Exists(appData & "Pulsar\ProjectSpideynn-Pulsar.jar") Then
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("*hidden-link*", appData & "\.ProjectSpideynn\Pulsar\ProjectSpideynn-Pulsar.jar")` and I cant figure out why.

Error: `An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not complete operation since a file already exists in this path 'C:\Users\Spideynn\AppData\Roaming.ProjectSpideynn\.ProjectSpideynn\Pulsar\ProjectSpideynn-Pulsar.jar'.`
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to mention, I cut out the download link for reasons of people downloading it.

Comment: is the error a secret?

Comment: Can't you simply use `else` rather than re-checking that file not exists

Comment: I had that earlier but it seemed that it was still executing the download bit of code...

Comment: check my answer for explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

the problem is that your if is wrong because exists() will return false so yu have

```
if not false then
```

that is the same than:

```
if true then
```

so youer statement is true you have to use an else in your fisrt IF

```
If File.Exists(appData & "Pulsar\ProjectSpideynn-Pulsar.jar") Then
    Dim startInfo As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    startInfo.Arguments = "java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar" & appData & "Pulsar\ProjectSpideynn-Pulsar.jar"
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    Process.Start(startInfo)
else
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("*hidden-link*", appData & "\.ProjectSpideynn\Pulsar\ProjectSpideynn-Pulsar.jar","","",false,100 ,true)
    Dim startInfo As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
    startInfo.FileName = "javaw.exe"
    startInfo.Arguments = "-Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar" & appData & "Pulsar\ProjectSpideynn-Pulsar.jar"
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    Process.Start(startInfo)
End If
```

for the new error try to overwrite your file.

Comment: overwrite it as mention avobe

Comment: Apparently my link is timing out An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The operation has timed out

Comment: credentials, maybe lag, maybe server not working at this moment

Comment: Im using dropbox: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/   which worked on my last test

Comment: The operation has timed out means that there was no response from server in the interval you specify. I checked the line i gave you and we are just giving 100ms thats not enough try changing that parameter to 5000

Comment: My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("*hidden-link*", appData & "\.ProjectSpideynn\Pulsar\ProjectSpideynn-Pulsar.jar","","",false,5000,true)

Comment: 1 more thing as well, is it possible in the method im using to setup a progress bar for the download?

Comment: yes is the param that its called show ui. just change it to true I think is the one before ,5000